# How to run python script which required root privilage for execution in apache with mod_python at openbsd

Tags: apache-2.2, python, openbsd, pf, mod-python

I am trying to run python script in Apache 2.x with mod_python.
I edited httpd.conf with publisher

```
     LoadModule python_module /usr/local/apache2/modules/mod_python.so
     <Directory /usr/local/apache2/htdocs/mod_python>

    SetHandler mod_python
    PythonHandler mod_python.publisher
    PythonDebug On
</Directory>
```

I am trying to add a rule in firewall using python script which require root privilege.
it's asking for root privilege ?
Please somebody help.

Answer (score 1):

Check it out.

"Similarly to pfctl(8), [py-pf](http://www.kernel-panic.it/programming/py-pf/pf1.html) sends commands to the kernel through the ioctl(2) interface provided by the pf(4) pseudo-device; this allows Python to natively communicate with the kernel, thanks to the fcntl and ctypes modules, with no need to write a specific C extension module."

So, check permissions in pf pseudo-device by user running apache.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `sudo` to run `pfctl` from your web application and you need to add the "apache" user to the `sudoers` file with the rights to run `pfctl` without asking for a password.

**NOTE:** To modify your `sudoers` file use the command `visudo` as root, or an account with elevated privileges to do so.

You might also not want to use the obsolete mod_python way of running python web apps. Something like [Bottle](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#deployment) or [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/deploying/uwsgi/) paired with the [nginx](http://nginx.org/) in base would be a better option.

Comment: I am not using pfctl through python.I am using py-pf for adding rule in firewall(pf).HOw can i execute python script require root privilage.
one more constraint from GUI ... exec in PHP is not allowed.. :(

Comment: Then the python script using py-pf must be standalone from the web app and run with sudo. It's that or running apache as root, which I strongly recommend against.